# "Greetings from Patrick of ABC company" or "Greetings by Patrick from at ABC company"

Tags: prepositions

For business needs, I need to connect to people on LinkedIn and send people a note to tell them who I am.

Should I say

1. "Greetings from Patrick of ABC company"
2. "Greetings by Patrick at ABC company"
   (I am not sure about the use of "at" here, but it was sent to me back by an Ozzie client)
3. "Greetings from Patrick of ABC company"

Which one is correct?

Comment: What is the difference between 1 & 3? (I'd most likely say "Greetings from Patrick _at_ ABC Company"; "of ABC company" is OK; definitely not "greetings by"!)

Comment: ***Ozzie*** is *Osborne*. It's pronounced the same, but Australians are ***Aussies***

Comment: "Greetings by" would mean that Patrick was somehow instrumental in _creating_ the greetings. Perhaps he would be a graphic designer or copywriter working for a greetings card company. It does not indicate on whose behalf they are being sent.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Unless the client is based in the Emerald City.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for pointing out that.